# multiple image using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multifile-uploader

```
 <?=form_open_multipart('upload/process');?>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="userfile[]" id="userfile" />
    <?=form_submit('upload', 'Upload');?>
<?=form_close();?>
```

i dont want to use uploadify or similar image uploading plugins. trying to keep it as light weight as possible

i want the user to be able to upload multiple images at once. once uploaded i want to make an entry of the image details in the database, and finally move the image to the uploads folder.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: asking a bit much there... I wouldnt call this lightweight but It's what I used https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-6.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1, I then wrote my own code for resizing and organising into folders. You might have to play around with it a bit to get it working though. I seem to remember it didn't work out the box for me. At the very least you can look at it and see how multiple image uploads are done

Comment: greate thanks to you  @ Webweaver :)

Comment: You really shouldn't repost the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955205/how-to-upload-multiple-photos-using-codeigniter) (albeit, this post isn't really a question) after your previous question is closed. You should edit the post in question first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25520/is-it-ever-acceptable-to-re-post-a-closed-question-e-g-after-editing-it-to-be

Comment: Have a look here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/71999/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look solution here:

http://www.indevcenter.com/simple-multiple-upload-using-codeigniter/

I believe that's what you need. :)

Cheers.